# Google sheets API - download data with no formatting

Tags: go, google-sheets, google-api, google-api-go-client

Using Go, when fetching sheet data, the data is arriving with its applied cell formatting 
i.e. `"$123,456"` while I need the original `123456`.

is there something in the api that can remove formatting? like `formatting: false`

code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/net/context"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
    "gopkg.in/Iwark/spreadsheet.v2"
)

func main() {
    service := authenticate()
    spreadsheet, err := service.FetchSpreadsheet(spreadsheetID)
    checkError(err)
    sheet, err := spreadsheet.SheetByIndex(1)
    checkError(err)

    for _, row := range sheet.Rows {
        var csvRow []string
        for _, cell := range row {
            csvRow = append(csvRow, cell.Value)
        }
        log.Println(csvRow)
    }
}

// function to authenticate on Google
func authenticate() *spreadsheet.Service {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("secret.json")
    checkError(err)
    conf, err := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(data, spreadsheet.Scope)
    checkError(err)
    client := conf.Client(context.TODO())
    service := spreadsheet.NewServiceWithClient(client)
    return service
}

func checkError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to retrieve `$123,456` as `123456` from Google Spreadsheet.
- `$123,456` is shown by the cell format. It's actually the number.
- You want to achieve this using `gopkg.in/Iwark/spreadsheet.v2` with golang.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using the service account with Sheets API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Modification points:

- When I saw [the script of the library of `gopkg.in/Iwark/spreadsheet.v2`](https://github.com/Iwark/spreadsheet), I noticed that the values are retrieved by the method of spreadsheets.get in Sheets API.
- Furthermore, it was found that [`spreadsheetId,properties.title,sheets(properties,data.rowData.values(formattedValue,note))` was used as the fields](https://github.com/Iwark/spreadsheet/blob/08231195c43bcd2dd8fd9a0b7e6bf5b57f085c90/service.go#L116). It seems that the fields is constant.

The reason of your issue is that the values are retrieved with `formattedValue`. In your case, the values are required to be retrieved with `userEnteredValue`.

When you want to achieve your goal using the library of `gopkg.in/Iwark/spreadsheet.v2`, in order to reflect above to the library, it is required to modify the script of library.

### Modified script:

Please modify the files of `gopkg.in/Iwark/spreadsheet.v2` as follows. Of course, please backup the original files in order to back to the original library.

#### 1. [service.go](https://github.com/Iwark/spreadsheet/blob/08231195c43bcd2dd8fd9a0b7e6bf5b57f085c90/service.go)

Modify [the line 116](https://github.com/Iwark/spreadsheet/blob/08231195c43bcd2dd8fd9a0b7e6bf5b57f085c90/service.go#L116) as follows.

From:

```
fields := "spreadsheetId,properties.title,sheets(properties,data.rowData.values(formattedValue,note))"
```

To:

```
fields := "spreadsheetId,properties.title,sheets(properties,data.rowData.values(formattedValue,note,userEnteredValue))"
```

#### 2. [sheet.go](https://github.com/Iwark/spreadsheet/blob/v2/sheet.go)

Modify [the line 52](https://github.com/Iwark/spreadsheet/blob/v2/sheet.go#L52) as follows.

From:

```
Value:  cellData.FormattedValue,
```

To:

```
Value:  strconv.FormatFloat(cellData.UserEnteredValue.NumberValue, 'f', 4, 64),
```

And add `"strconv"` to `import` section like below.

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "strings"
    "strconv"
)
```

#### 3. [cell_data.go](https://github.com/Iwark/spreadsheet/blob/v2/cell_data.go)

Modify [the line 8](https://github.com/Iwark/spreadsheet/blob/v2/cell_data.go#L8) as follows.

From:

```
// UserEnteredFormat *CellFormat `json:"userEnteredFormat"`
```

To:

```
UserEnteredFormat struct {
    NumberValue float64 `json:"numberValue"`
} `json:"userEnteredFormat"`
```

#### Result:

In this case, your script is not required to be modified. After above modification, when you run your script, you can see `[123456.0000]` at the console. As an important point, it seems that this library uses the values as the string type. In this modification, I used this. But if you want to use it as other type, please modify the library.

### Other pattern:

As the other pattern for achieving your goal, how about using google-api-go-client? About this, you can see it at [Go Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/go). When google-api-go-client is used, the sample script becomes as follows. In this case, as a test case, the method of spreadsheets.get was used.

#### Sample script 1:

In this sample script, `authenticate()` and `checkError()` in your script are used by modifying.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"

    "golang.org/x/net/context"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
    "google.golang.org/api/sheets/v4"
)

func main() {
    c := authenticate()
    sheetsService, err := sheets.New(c)
    checkError(err)
    spreadsheetId := "###"  // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
    ranges := []string{"Sheet1"}  // Please set the sheet name.
    resp, err := sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Get(spreadsheetId).Ranges(ranges...).Fields("sheets.data.rowData.values.userEnteredValue").Do()
    checkError(err)
    for _, row := range resp.Sheets[0].Data[0].RowData {
        for _, col := range row.Values {
            fmt.Println(col.UserEnteredValue)
        }
    }
}

func authenticate() *http.Client {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("serviceAccount_20190511.json")
    checkError(err)
    conf, err := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(data, sheets.SpreadsheetsScope)
    checkError(err)
    client := conf.Client(context.TODO())
    return client
}

func checkError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
}
```

#### Sample script 2:

When spreadsheets.values.get is used, the script of `main()` is as follows.

```
func main() {
    c := authenticate()
    sheetsService, err := sheets.New(c)
    checkError(err)
    spreadsheetId := "###"  // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
    sheetName := "Sheet1"  // Please set the sheet name.
    resp, err := sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, sheetName).ValueRenderOption("UNFORMATTED_VALUE").Do()
    checkError(err)
    fmt.Println(resp.Values)
}
```

- Here, [`UNFORMATTED_VALUE`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueRenderOption) is used for retrieving the values without the cell format. This has already been answered by [alberto vielma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59552455)

### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [google-api-go-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client)
- [Go Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/go)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: great answer! I used the "other pattern"

Comment: @EldadT Thank you for replying and testing. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a way. In the [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) endpoint, there is a request parameter called [valueRenderOption](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get#query-parameters), which one of its values is *UNFORMATTED_VALUE*, as its name suggests, it will give you back all the data without format.

[Try this Request](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get?apix_params=%7B%22spreadsheetId%22%3A%22your-id%22%2C%22range%22%3A%22A1%22%2C%22valueRenderOption%22%3A%22UNFORMATTED_VALUE%22%7D) with the range of values you want to play around with the API and see in that way the unformatted values it will return.